# Apache cxf Jax Rs encoding issue

Tags: apache, jboss, character-encoding, jax-rs, cxf

I am using jaxrs with Apache cxf . Below is the xml config

```
<jaxrs:server id="accountrs" address="/rservice">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="accountService"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean='jsonProvider' />
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>
```

For some of my post methods i see that that the double byte charectors are getting distorted and appearing as garbled charectors and getting stored in the database .

I am reading the json body as string and not as any bean in my service implementation method  . Below is the sample

```
@POST
    @Path("/accounts/")
    public Account getAccount(String jsonBody) {
       //Business code goes here
    }
```

I am stuck with this for a while now . Can some one help

Answer (score 1):

Try adding @Consumes("application/json;charset=utf-8") to your getAccount resource. You may also need to specify a @Produces annotation too with a content type and a charset.

Comment: Tried this ... Still no luck . Pls help

Comment: Can you show the definition of your jsonProvider? I imagine there'll be a setting on that bean to set the CharSet.